# Input in Vector

Tags: c++, vector, input, 2d

```
       int n, q;
       cin>>n>>q;
       vector<vector<int>> v1 (n);
       for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          int k;
          cin>>k;
          for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
               cin>>v1[i][j];
               int temp;
               cin>>temp;
               v1[i].push_back(temp); */        
        }
    }
```

Above written code only works, if i take input using code that are in comments. Why can't i take input using cin>>v1[i][j]; ?

Comment: There are no numbers in any comment section in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't allocate space for k elements in the inner vector

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v1(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  int k;
  std::cin >> k;
  v1[i].resize(k);  // Or v1[i] = std::vector<int>(k)
  for(int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
     std::cin >> v1[i][j]; 
  }
}
```